# retrieving values from nested JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON which is mentioned below.

```
 {"Orders"
   [{"BusinessUnit":"TS",
     "DeliveryDetails":
             [{"SlotStartDateTime":"2015-03-30T16","DeliveryOption":"Home    
             Delivery","ReservationID":"13349259","PersonInfoShipTo":
             {"Address":"OrganizationName":"HP","BuildingTypeID":"",
             "IsCommercialAddress":"false","PostalCode":"56001",
             "City":"Bangalore","AddressLine3":"A3","AddressLine2":"A2",
             "AddressLine1":"A1","IsPAFValidated":"true",
             "GridRef":"0473601734","State":"KA","AddressLine4":"A4",
             "Country":"IN"}},"ShipNode":"NODEUK","SlotEndDateTime":"2015-
              03-30T17"}],
    "FulfilmentID":"a9466f83-938d-4115-a3d4-62ff4bdcd1b6",
    "OrderTypeIndicator":"SalesOrder"}]}
```

Question:
I am able to take the values of `BusinessUnit`, `FulfilmentID` & `OrderTypeIndicator`. But, I am unable to take the values present inside the inner json object `DeliveryDetails`. Could anyone help me on taking those values

Comment: share your code which is unable to access `DeliveryDetails`

Comment: `JsonObject.get("DeliveryDetails")` whill return you `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`

Comment: thanks Pravin n Lentz.. I am using Json.Simple jar for this operation. But, I am unable to achieve what you have suggested. Could you please guide me with the correct jar..?. I am very new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DeliveryDetails" is mapped to a json array object with a single json object inside.

Try doing:

```
json.getJSONArray("Orders").get(0).get("DeliveryDetails").get(0)
```

Of course it would be better to check first if keys exists and the size of json arrays returned before retrieving actual indices.